# View visible across perspectives

Tags: eclipse, rcp, workbench

I have an Eclipse RCP application that defines multiple perspectives. The default perspective allows opening views (through the `showView` method) that are not defined in the `IPerspectiveLayout` class.

When switching to another perspective, these views disappear as they belong to the default one.

Is there a way of making these views persistable through perspective changes?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no way to do that in RCP other than to declare a view as "sticky". But the sticky views have their limitations, use it with great care.

http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fextension-points%2Forg_eclipse_ui_views.html

> A sticky view is a view that will appear by default across all
>   perspectives in a window once it is opened. Its initial placement is
>   governemed by the location attribute, but nothing prevents it from
>   being moved or closed by the user. Use of this element will only cause
>   a placeholder for the view to be created, it will not show the view.
>   Please note that usage of this element should be done with great care
>   and should only be applied to views that truely have a need to live
>   across perspectives.

Answer (score 0):

The view won't appear in the perspective, unless you define, that the view belongs to this perspective, while creating perspective layout or unless user opens it in the, using some action. So, you have to consider adding view placeholders to the perspective layout, see `org.eclipse.ui.IFolderLayout.addPlaceholder(String viewId)` method.